# Big MySQL product history table partitioning?

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, partitioning

I am developing warehouse control system written by php, laravel framework, mariadb. To get all info about each product we use products "history" table, that logs all actions taken on certain product. This table started to expand very quickly and now we have ~15 million rows innoDB table that started to work slow especially when running function, that takes full analysis about how much products sold, created, thrown away etc, then it takes all 15 million rows on one query.. So I started searching ways, how to manage with this big table, because indexing doesnt working anymore.
I am starting to think about spliting/partitioning this table by date, maybe action? so maybe anyone have any experience with that and can share some advice with me? big thanks for any help!

[image]
`` CREATE TABLE `history` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `barcode` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bag` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `action` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `place` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `old_price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rotation` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `discount` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `discount_type` tinyint(2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `original` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `was_in_shop` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `cate` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'grupe',
  `sub_cate` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `helper` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `barcode` (`barcode`),
  KEY `action` (`action`),
  KEY `original` (`original`),
  KEY `created_at` (`created_at`),
  KEY `bag` (`bag`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16274267 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ``

for example query:

```
select  cate,
SUM(amount) AS amount, SUM(IF(discount>0,(price*amount)-discount,
                    (price*amount))) AS sum, SUM(IF(discount>0,IF(discount_type=1,
                                            (discount*price)/100,discount),0)
   ) AS discount from  history
    where  (history.action = '4'
              and  history.created_at >= '2017-11-01 00:00:00'
              and  history.created_at <= '2017-11-23 23:59:59'
           )
      and  LENGTH(barcode) > 7
      and  history.deleted_at is null
    group by  cate
```

this query is used to get amount, sum, discount info about sold products (action 4) in this example it is information between 2017-11-01 and 2017-11-23 and `EXPLAIN` gives me this:

`id - 1
select_type - SIMPLE
table - history
type - ref
possible_keys - action,created_at
key - action
key_len - 5
ref - const
rows - 1444272
Extra - Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort`

so it takes 1.5 million rows with table that holds data from 2017-01-01 until now, so after 2 years it will take 3 million rows and etc... when I need to take  just 2017-11 products sold information. And I have a lot of more queries similar to this one.

Comment: What do you mean by "indexing doesnt working anymore"?

Comment: I have already 5 indexes (right side table on attached image) adding more index doesnt speed things up anymore.

Comment: Does an `EXPLAIN` onto your slow queries support this hypothesis?

Comment: Screenshots are almost useless here. Please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to describe your situation plus show the queries involved.

Comment: updated main question with additional info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use smaller datatypes (shrinking the table size helps with performance) `INT` takes 4 bytes; other sizes are available.
- `PARTITIONing` does *not* intrinsically provide any performance.
- `history.deleted_at is null` -- consider actually deleting the rows.
- Learn about 'composite' indexes, such as `INDEX(action, created_at)` .  (Only one index is used at a time.)

The big improvement comes by building and maintaining Summary Table(s); see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables .  Then run the queries against them.  And most of the indexes can go away.

Fix some of those; then I can help you further.

**More**

A Comment asks about how to maintain the summary table id two different ways.  Either can be viable, depending on more, as yet unspecified, details:

- `INSERT INTO Fact` table, and immediately use IODKU to insert or update the Summary table.
- Do the summarization "on demand" -- This, when a user asks for the data, first run the `INSERT .. SELECT ..` to capture the not-yet-summarized rows and put the counts/subtotals into the Summary table.

The latter choice works, but there are two things to watch out for:

- If no user comes along in a long time, then the summarization could be costly.  The simple fix is to also have a cron job periodically "catching up".  Be sure to interlock the code so that cron and user are not both updating the same rows at the same time.
- If the Summary table has a 'natural' `PRIMARY KEY`, such as a date (day or hour) and a couple of dimension values, then you are like have trouble with the `INSERT`.  Either avoid that as the PK (thereby leading to multiple rows, which is not 'bad') or use IODKU in the form `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY ... SELECT ... GROUP BY ...;` and use the `VALUES(xx)` function.

Comment: I have read about Summary Table(s). What I understood from this article is that I would need to INSERT...SELECT from history to summary table. But in my case I need "up-to-the-second" reports, because all statistic reports are "live", so there is recommended "as needed" type. So I want to ask if it is better to insert/update summary table from "history" table every time I refresh page and then select all info from this new summary table than just select that info from "history" table directly? or maybe there is other way to do that?

Comment: @Tomas - I provide some more hints.